# Mocking find($collection) in repository pattern in Laravel with Mockery

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit, mockery

I'm doing unit testing and my repository has this method:

```php
/**
 * @param int|Collection $id
 * @return MyModel|Collection|null
 */
 public function find($id);
```

I tried this:

```php
$this->package_repo = Mockery::mock(PackageRepositoryInterface::class);
$this->app->instance('Package', $this->package_repo);
// ...
$this->ticket_repo->shouldReceive("find")->with(collect([]))->andReturn(/*...*/);

//...

echo $this->ticket_repo->find(collect([]));  // Failed here.
```

The test immediately failed, and I think it's because the 2 collections in the `shouldReceive` expectation statement and the actual `find` statement are distinct objects.

If I want to mock the behavior of `$this->ticket_repo->find($ids)`, what should I do?

Or rather, if there is a better way to design a testable algorithm, how would it be? Because I would like to have all the ids to I want to find be in an array, and be constructed into a single SQL select query, instead of a few hundred separate ones, for performance purposes.

Also asked here: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/testing/mocking-findcollection-in-repository-pattern-in-laravel-with-mockery#

Answer (score 0):

You have to mock a concrete class and not the interface. Since you haven't provided the name I'm just guessing:

```
$mock = Mockery::mock(TicketRepo::class);
$this->app->swap('PackageRepo', $mock);
```

So now whenever someone asks for an instance by the Interface name they'll get the mock.